# asterisk sip gone unreachable on sipml5 page load

Tags: asterisk, sipml

I have installed and configure asterisk on my server, everything is working fine, but the problem is when user connected first time following message appears on sip debug :

```
 [May 27 22:13:25] WARNING[20193]: chan_sip.c:3727 __sip_xmit: sip_xmit of 0x7f16b400bdb0 (len 646) to 192.168.0.150:61709 returned -1: No such file or directory
Scheduling destruction of SIP dialog '32729691-cce2-c278-d528-924721cfddca' in 32000 ms (Method: REGISTER)
```

but on refreshing page sip peer is reachable.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, I have an error in my sip.conf file, changing sip.conf solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Seems like communication is one way only. The asterisk receives, but cannot send. Check firewalls, NATs, routing.